# Record each character from UITextfield into NSDictionary in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uicollectionviewcell

I am using UICollectionview and each cell have UITextfield and i am trying to get complete string from and each textfield and saving into dictionary. i used following code

```
  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    if (textField.tag==100) {
         [m11ThumbImage_MutCaptionDictionary setValue:[textField.text stringByAppendingString:string] forKey:@"image_0001"];
    }
    if (textField.tag==101) {
        [m11ThumbImage_MutCaptionDictionary setValue:[textField.text stringByAppendingString:string] forKey:@"image_0002"];
    }
    }
```

I tried:

Using above code I able to set string correctly but, if i delete character the above method not called and dictionary not updated.

TextFieldDidBeginEditing call initially and able to record 1 character only. also tried other delegate methods

Expected Output:

```
{
image_0001: All Character,
image_0002: A
}
```

Any help will up-voted. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange` gets called before `text field` actually changes its text, if you need to get the update value then do like

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
      
    if (textField.tag==100) {
         [m11ThumbImage_MutCaptionDictionary setValue:[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] forKey:@"image_0001"];
    }
    else if (textField.tag==101) {
    [m11ThumbImage_MutCaptionDictionary setValue:[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] forKey:@"image_0002"];
}
}
```

**updated answer**

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
      
        NSString * currentStr = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if (textField.tag==100) {
         [m11ThumbImage_MutCaptionDictionary setValue:currentStr forKey:@"image_0001"];
    }
    else if (textField.tag==101) {
    [m11ThumbImage_MutCaptionDictionary setValue:currentStr forKey:@"image_0002"];
     }
  return YES;
}
```

**alternate way**

add in your viewdidload  To get `EditingChanged  textfield event`, I suggested add selector as

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

As textfield value changed, the changed value you will get from this `textChanged:` selector.

```
 -(void)textChanged:(UITextField *)textField
   {
    NSLog(@"textfield data %@ ",textField.text);
    if (textField.tag==100) {
     [m11ThumbImage_MutCaptionDictionary setValue:[textField.text stringByAppendingString:string] forKey:@"image_0001"];
   }
 else if (textField.tag==101) {
    [m11ThumbImage_MutCaptionDictionary setValue:[textField.text stringByAppendingString:string] forKey:@"image_0002"];
}
}
```

Comment: shouldChangeCharactersInRange  not calling if i delete character so. i cant record them how to fix this?

Comment: are you set the delegate of your textfield

Comment: Yes. thats why shouldChangeCharactersInRange calling

Comment: @AvijitNagare - my bro, shouldChangeCharactersInRange is the best place to capure the current text

Comment: @AvijitNagare = else we go for alternate idea wait